# What does "Canceled on identification as a pivot" mean?

Tags: postgresql, transaction-isolation

I use a postgres database and I see the following error message:

> could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
> DETAIL:  Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during conflict out checking.
> HINT:  The transaction might succeed if retried.

The issue is that I have two transactions which are executed concurrently and they can influence each other.

**This question is about understanding the error message itself**, not about fixing the issue. I would love if somebody could walk me through it. Some questions I have:

- What is the mentioned "identification"?
- What is a pivot in this case?
- What is "conflict out checking"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with all the relevant internals, but I'd take a read through the [releavant source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/b0c066297bdac901a13a5a900a197697a026b357/src/backend/storage/lmgr/predicate.c#L4136) - it's pretty well-documented.

Comment: You probably need to study Cahill's PhD theses.  http://hdl.handle.net/2123/5353